# Xamarin iOS - why does Transporter not find my icons?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, ipa

I have app on xamarin forms. I am trying to publish the app in Apple Store(with Transporter app). I have this error:

```
 ERROR ITMS-90022: "Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPhone / iPod Touch of exactly '120x120' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions >= 7.0. To support older versions of iOS, the icon may be required in the bundle outside of an asset catalog. Make sure the Info.plist file includes appropriate entries referencing the file. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/user_interface"

ERROR ITMS-90023: "Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '152x152' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions >= 7.0. To support older operating systems, the icon may be required in the bundle outside of an asset catalog. Make sure the Info.plist file includes appropriate entries referencing the file. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/user_interface"

ERROR ITMS-90023: "Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '167x167' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions supporting iPad Pro. To support older operating systems, the icon may be required in the bundle outside of an asset catalog. Make sure the Info.plist file includes appropriate entries referencing the file. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/user_interface"

ERROR ITMS-90023: "Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '76x76' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions >= 7.0. To support older operating systems, the icon may be required in the bundle outside of an asset catalog. Make sure the Info.plist file includes appropriate entries referencing the file. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/user_interface"
```

if briefly 4 files are missing('120x120','152x152','167x167','76x76' ). I tried different options and different services, this is my last one(from Contents.json).

```
....
{
  "scale": "1x",
  "size": "76x76",
  "idiom": "ipad",
  "filename": "Icon76.png"
},
{
  "scale": "2x",
  "size": "76x76",
  "idiom": "ipad",
  "filename": "Icon152.png"
},
{
  "scale": "2x",
  "size": "83.5x83.5",
  "idiom": "ipad",
  "filename": "Icon167.png"
},
```

this is my info.plist:

[image]

these files are present why am i getting the error? any advice i would be grateful. already spent a lot of time.

Comment: did you explicitly set, that your assets are appIcon provider?

Answer (score 1):

1. Open your `Info.plist` in iOS project
2. Add XSAppIconAssets property
3. Enter the assets name and the icon set

Please, check the demonstration from the working project below

[image]

Comment: I have this string. I updated my question. Maybe I need delete string CFBundleIconName?

Comment: Yes, please delete, I don't have it in the info.plist file

Comment: I did it, but I have same error (4 errors)

Comment: can you attach you appicon screenshot from assets?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue. The problem was somewhere in the project file and not with the icons. after many tries I created a new project(xamarin forms->xamarin.ios) and copied the required dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue not long ago on VS22 v4.3.7. The icons we're all added and I had them referenced correctly in the info.plist. It seems my Release|iPhone configuration in the iOS Project settings was the problem. I created a new project and checked the configurations there and compared to mine. Here is an example of a working configuration that I have:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|iPhone' ">
<DebugType>none</DebugType>
<Optimize>true</Optimize>
<OutputPath>bin\iPhone\Release</OutputPath>
<ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
<WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
<MtouchArch>ARM64</MtouchArch>
<CodesignKey>Your_Distribution_Profile</CodesignKey>
<CodesignEntitlements>Entitlements.plist</CodesignEntitlements>
<OptimizePNGs>true</OptimizePNGs>
<CodesignProvision>Your_Distribution_Provisioning</CodesignProvision>
<BuildIpa>true</BuildIpa>
<PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
```

Hope it helps!